# Correct way to transfer SelectedItemViewModel to another page in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1, mvvm-light, win-universal-app

I'm currently building a universal app but I'm concentrating on the WP8.1 part of it right now. I'm using MVVMLight with this project.

For simplicity sake, we'll just assume that I only have 2 pages in the project.

Page1.xaml contains a list which has various items. The Page1.xaml is binded to its own ViewModel i.e. Page1ViewModel. Each item in the list represents a viewModel i.e. ItemViewModel.

When I tap on an item, I call the following code:

```
public RelayCommand<ItemViewModel> ItemTapCommand
{
    get
    {
        return this._itemTapCommand ?? (this._itemTapCommand = 
                new RelayCommand<ItemViewModel>((msg) => 
                ExecuteItempTapCommand(msg)));
    }
}
```

When an item in the list is tapped, I call the following code:

```
private object ExecuteItempTapCommand(ItemViewModel selectedItemViewModel)
{
    Page2ViewModel page2ViewModel = 
    SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<ItemViewModel>();

    page2ViewModel.SelectedItem = selectedItemViewModel;

    _navigationService.Navigate(typeof(Page2), 
     selectedItemViewModel);
     return null;
}
```

As you can see I'm using my Ioc to create get an instance of my Page2ViewModel and I then set the `SelectedItem` to the selectedItemViewModel.

Once it is set, I navigate to Page2 which is binded to my Page2ViewModel.

What I want to know is, is the above is ok to do? I've seen plenty of examples when dealing with passing object from one page to another is done by passing an Id for example and then I request the information from Page2, but why request it again when most of the information I need is already in my SelectedItemViewModel since it represents the tapped item in my list in Page1.

If it's not correct, what is the best way to go about this using MVVMLight?

Can you provide a sample? I've seen something about Messaging but I'm not sure how this would work as if I navigate to my page2, the Page2ViewModel will only be initiated when the page is created, so how can it receive a message? The way I have it above seems to initiate the Page2ViewModel and my Pag2 loads, it's re-using it and everything bind correctly but I'm not sure this is the correct way to go about it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your Page2ViewModel, why not use

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Page2SelectedItem = e.Parameter as ItemViewModel; 
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
```

It looks like you are packing that data in with your _navigationService.Navigate call already.

With that set up, what happens if you just change to:

```
private object ExecuteItempTapCommand(ItemViewModel selectedItemViewModel)
{        
    _navigationService.Navigate(typeof(Page2), selectedItemViewModel);
    return null; 
}
```

Comment: I'm sure that would work but aren't you breaking mvvm rules by using code behind?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ViewModel to get it if you do some work before that.

Read this blog post by Marco Minerva called [Calling ViewModel methods in response to Page navigation events using MVVM Light in WinRT](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/05/07/calling-viewmodel-methods-in-response-to-page-navigation-events-using-mvvm-light-in-winrt/)

which explains how to react to OnNavigatedTo and OnNavigatedFrom in the ViewModel.

It's a very cool solution.

Comment: Thanks for that article. Interesting alright! Still relies on code behind though accessing the ViewModel. I'm not sure what you mean by 'You can use the ViewModel to get it if you do some work before that'?? Are you answering my question saying it is ok to do what I did or are you saying something else? Thanks.

Comment: @Thierry When I said you needed to do some work first, I meant implement BindablePage and then make every page inherit from it. This way you have the code-behind logic in only one place and it's not problematic as it's OK that View knows about the ViewModel.